# interactive page-load without javascript

Tags: html, css

How does this page achieve interactive page-load without javascript?

https://jgthms.com/web-design-in-4-minutes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site in question in fact uses JavaScript.

Looking at its source (*right-click ➡️ View Page Source*), you  can find the `<script>` tag near the end.

Comment: True, but that JavaScript seems to be something to do with Google Fonts, not with the progressive page load.

Comment: @thanks_in_advance And the progressive display, too. Clicking "first thing" calls the event handler registered on line 300, for example